# Accessing an unreturned list within a function in Python without disturbing Scipy

Tags: python, python-2.x, scipy

Here is the code I'm working on. I'm trying to find the optimum alpha value to get the minimum MAE/MAD. With `scipy.optimize`, it works quite well. However, when `scipy.optimize` achieves the optimum alpha, it also achieves the forecast values that essentially I'm trying to get to. Is there a way to return or access and store those forecast values named `yPredList` without disturbing the work `scipy.optimize` is doing? Because otherwise I'm going to have to do the forecast calculations from scratch, which is unnecessary. Thanks.

```
import scipy.optimize as spop
ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.
def ErrorCalc(alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
    yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
    for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
        yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
    NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
    NewError = np.mean(NewList)
    return NewError

result = spop.minimize_scalar(ErrorCalc,bounds=[0,1],args=ObservedSpeeds,method='bounded')
alpha = result.x
```

Comment: Do I get it right if I say that you are asking us how to add a feature in your code? If so this question is off-topic as the code is not working as intended.

Comment: This has now been answered on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know SciPy or anything about the problem you're solving. I can however comment on coding style.

## Style is important

Python has a style convention referred to as PEP 8. The full specification can be found [on Python's website](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). One often repeated mantra is "readability counts", because code is often read more than written. Because consistency improves readability, and conventions enforce consistency, I think following the PEP 8 style guide is important. It will make it easier for other people to understand your code.

The following sections describe the changes I think you could make to improve the style and in turn readability of the code.

#### Use newlines to separate logical units

This will make the code look better organized and it will make it easier to at a glance get a grasp of what parts the program is composed of.

```
import scipy.optimize as spop
ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.
def ErrorCalc(alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
    yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
    for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
        yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
    NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
    NewError = np.mean(NewList)
    return NewError
```

becomes

```
import scipy.optimize as spop

ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.

def ErrorCalc(alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
    yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation

    for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
        yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))

    NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
    NewError = np.mean(NewList)

    return NewError
```

#### snake_case vs CamelCase

In Python, `snake_case` style is used for variable and function names while `CamelCase` is used for class names. To someone used to this convention (like me), your code is very confusing at first.

This includes changes to `ErrorCalc`, `ObservedSpeeds`, `NewError` etc.

#### Allow operators some space

I think the most significant possible style change would be to add some spacing around or after some operators. Generally putting a space after `,` and spaces around binary operators like `+`, `-` etc improve readability a lot.

#### Conclusion

With a few minor changes, your code can become much easier for other (and yourself) to understand. Learning this is something that will benefit you in the future as well.